# Mysql query to proper Laravel $query

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I have this logic query that doesn't work because I need to Join like 4 different tables, which is insane but please help me out, I will find a better way in the future.

```
select * from approvals
    where approvable_type = 
        (select model from permission_configs
            where variable = (
                select permission_slug from role_permission
                    where role_id = (
                        select role_id from role_user 
                            where user_id = approvals.user_id) ) )
```

Please give me the above query in Eloquent with multiple join! I will forever be grateful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refactor your query using `inner join` instead of `where` and subquery

```
  select * 
  from approvals a 
  INNER JOIN permission_configs p  ON a.approvable_type  = p.model
  INNER JOIN role_permission r ON p.variable = r.permission_slug 
  INNER JOIN role_user u ON r.role_id = u.role_id 
  WHERE u.user_id = a.user_id
```

once done, you could take a look at `Eloquent` for join